# Ascertain international date format in Twig (or JavaScript), for use elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, twig

In Twig is it possible to ascertain the international date format, to perform the following in JavaScript:

```
var frmt;
{% if usformat %}
    frmt = "MM/DD";
{% else %}
    frmt = "DD/MM";
{% endif %}
document.getElementById("dt_tm").value = 
some_fn(document.getElementById("inp-dt-tm").value, "{{ frmt }}/YYYY HH:mm");
```

Where some_fn is defined elsewhere, but takes a date / time formatting string.  How to achieve the "if usformat?"

Alternatively can this be achieved in JavaScript?

```
var frmt;
if (usformat)
    frmt = "MM/DD";
else
    frmt = "DD/MM";
document.getElementById("dt_tm").value = 
some_fn(document.getElementById("inp-dt-tm").value, "{{ frmt }}/YYYY HH:mm");
```

What about using moment.js?

Comment: the function `some_fn` is a js function?

Comment: @Matteo Yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

Simply output the twig value as follow:

```
document.getElementById("dt_tm").value = 
some_fn(document.getElementById("inp-dt-tm").value, "{{ frmt }}/YYYY HH:mm");
```

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry, yes that was what I meant to say in the example.  I've updated the question.  It does help, but it is the "usformat" that I can't figure out.

Comment: hi @tyebillion you want to intercept the browser configuration?

Comment: hi @tyebillion you want to intercept the browser configuration?

Comment: Yes, I want to know whether or not the client (browser) is in US date format.